# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'categoryOptions' available as request attribute

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc

I know there are many threads on this topic i have tried most of them, still cant fix my problem.I am using `SpringMVC` and `MongoDB` What i am trying to achieve is, I will Store some data in database and then i will retrieve it back from data base to a select options. here is my codes.

**Jsp page..**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <title>Master Referral</title>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />' >
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/stylesvitalbeat.css" />' >


    </head>
    <body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
                 <form action="http://localhost:8080/LoginMavenSpringMVC/admin/create" method="post">
                 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                     <label class="control-label">Create Category:</label></div>
                     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm field_color"  name="categoryName" placeholder="Name of the Category">
                         </div>
                     <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm   height_margin"  name="create" value="Create">
                     </div>
                      </form>
<div>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="http://localhost:8080/LoginMavenSpringMVC/admin/saveReferral" method="post">
         <div class="row margin_div">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                <label class="control-label">Select Category</label>
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
             <f:select path="categoryOptions">
            <f:options items="${list}"/>
         </f:select>
                              </div>

                </div>

</div>
```

**controller class**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.java.Dao.services.RegisterDao;
import com.java.Dao.services.RegisterDaoImplementaion;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class ReferralController {

    @Autowired
    RegisterDao registerDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@ModelAttribute("create") Category create){
        ModelAndView model =new ModelAndView("referralPage");
        System.out.println("Referral Controller.");     
    System.out.println( create.getCategoryName());
    if((StringUtils.hasText(create.getId()))) {
        registerDao.UpdateCategory(create);
    } else {
        registerDao.addCategory(create);
    }
    List<Category> list= registerDao.categoryList();
    model.addObject("list", list);
   return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/saveReferral", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("saveReferral") Referrals referral){
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("referralPage");        
        return model;
    }
}
```

**Dao services**

```
dao class...
package com.java.Dao.services;

import java.util.List;
import com.java.Package.Login.Category;


public interface RegisterDao {
public void addCategory(Category createCategory);
    public void UpdateCategory(Category createCategory);
    public List<Category> categoryList();
}
```

**Dao Implementation**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.java.Package.Login.Category;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;


@Repository
public class RegisterDaoImplementaion implements RegisterDao {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    public static final String Collection_Category="CategoryList";
public void addCategory(Category createCategory) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        createCategory.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        System.out.println("Object in Repos::"+createCategory);
        mongoTemplate.insert(createCategory, Collection_Category);
    }
    public void UpdateCategory(Category createCategory) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mongoTemplate.insert(createCategory, Collection_Category);      
    }
    @Override
    public List<Category> categoryList() {      
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(Category.class, Collection_Category);
    }
}
```

**Class to map categoryOptions**

```
public class Referrals {
    private String categoryOptions;

    public String getCategoryOptions() {
        return categoryOptions;
    }

    public void setCategoryOptions(String categoryOptions) {
        this.categoryOptions = categoryOptions;
    }
}
```

**and I am getting this error log**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/LoginMavenSpringMVC] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/referralPage.jsp at line 366

363:             </div>
364:              <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
365:              
366:              <f:select path="categoryOptions">
367:                <f:options items="${list}"/>
368:              </f:select>
369:             <!--  <select class="form-control input-sm" name="categoryOptions" >


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'categoryOptions' available as request attribute
```

Where I am getting wrong? I have tried solutions from different question but couldn't  solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing adding Referrals object to model.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveReferral", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("saveReferral") Referrals referral){
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("referralPage");     
        model.addAttribute("categoryOptions",new Referrals());   //or referral
        return model;
    }
```

Exception is occuring because of `<f:select path="categoryOptions">`,you have mentioned `categoryOptions` in path but no where you are `returning` to this `jsp` with `categoryOptions`.

**Update :** So this says whenever you are loading `referral jsp`, you have to load with `categoryOptions bean`

And in below lines list is added to model using `model.addObject()` but path variable `categoryOptions` is missing. So after the line `model.addObject("list", list);` add **`model.addAttribute("categoryOptions", new Referrals());`**

```
<f:select path="categoryOptions">
   <f:options items="${list}"/>
</f:select>
```

Comment: see this "/saveReferral" is nor being called right now there is a create button which will add some name to database and the select option should show the added name in its option.

Comment: on what request u are getting this exception? `create`??

Comment: when admin logs in this page will be shown, this point only it is giving this exception

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.